# Tapping power from series of solar panels

Tags: batteries, solar-energy

I'm developing a device that runs off 24V DC. I'll be installing it at a client's site who has arrays of solar panel, with 24 panels in series, making it a **1000V** system. Can I tap one panel from the series to get around 40 volts, so that i can give it to the charge controller and then to the load?

Would that affect the complete series? A sample series is shown in the figure.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fWH8Fa.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Why? Why not downstream of the inverter like everyone else?

Comment: That's actually 1000V DC, and converting that to 24VDC isn't gonna be easy. Also the inverter is located slightly far from the device.

Comment: _Downstream_ of the inverter. Slightly far? Too long for an AC cable to carry whatever power you need at 24 VDC?

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm doing as of now. Tapping 500V AC and rectifying it post stepping down.

Comment: Then problem solved!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tapping power off just one panel will reduce the power that the whole string can produce.

Where panels are connected in series, the current is limited to whatever the lowest generating panel is producing.  By stealing some current from one panel, you reduce the amount it can supply to the rest of the string.